# MS Access vba delete excel worksheet (2010)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to delete a worksheet from MS Access.

There's a lot of data on the sheet, including two charts.  Instead of trying to delete all the data, I want to delete the sheet and re-add it.

I've looked up several ways to delete a sheet with MS Access and found the following .delete as the easiest, but it doesn't work.  The "if not" works and goes through the .delete statement, but the .add(after...) fails.

I obviously have something wrong and any input is appreciated.

```
Dim wkb as excel.workbook
Dim wksheetname as excel.worksheet
Dim strsheetname as string

wkb.Activate

On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSheetName = wkb.Sheets(StrSheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not wksSheetName Is Nothing Then
    wkb.Sheets(StrSheetName).Delete
    Set wksSheetName = Nothing
End If

wkb.Sheets.Add(After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count)).Name = StrSheetName
Set wksSheetName = wkb.Sheets(StrSheetName)
```

Comment: What if you split the `.add` line? I'm not sure but you may not be able to `add` and give `name` in same line.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce.  The .add works great.  If I manually delete the worksheet before running the code, the new worksheet is added.

Comment: Looking at your code. looks like `StrSheetName` is empty. Could that be the error?

Comment: Use. The. Macro. Recorder. It's a gift.

Comment: @foxfire, I didn't show all the code because it's large, but it is set.

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat simpler method works here:

```
Const WorksheetName As String = "Sheet2"

Dim Workbook        As Excel.Workbook
Dim Worksheet       As Excel.Worksheet

Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook

For Each Worksheet In Workbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name = WorksheetName Then
        Worksheet.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Set Worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Count))
Worksheet.Name = WorksheetName
```